# Merging two files based on the first column depending on specific pattern's location in file 1

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

I have the following files:

File 1 (around 7000 lines):

```
1010089 1402 6814 5543
1010121 6948 1402 2344
1305789 7589 7890 1402
3456889 1254 7389 1256
```

File 2 (around 300k lines):

```
1010089 26 48 33
1010121 21 62 49
```

I would like to merge the two files based on the first column depending on 1402-s location in file 1. For example, if 1402 is in the second column, I want to print the first column of file 1, the second column of file 1 and the second column of file 2. If 1402 is in the third column, I want to print the first column of file 1, the third column of file 1 and the third column of file 2.

1402 can occur in any column, not only in the second or the third. However, it does not occur more than once/line. If $1 from file 2 does not include $1 of file 1, I want to print $1, 1402 and unknown.

Desired output:

```
1010089 1402 26
1010121 1402 62
1305789 1402 unknown
3456889 0000 unknown
```

I use the following script to merge the two files:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in arr){print $0,arr[$1]}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Can `1402` occur after 3rd column of first file? If so, should they be considered or not?

Comment: 1402 can occur after the 3rd column, yes, but it only occurs in one column/ line. Question edited.

Comment: I edited the question again. In theory all lines should have 1402 one time, and all of $1 should present in file 1, but just to be safe, I would prefer to do what you recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I knew what file1, file2, and each of the columns represent I would come up with batter variable names but I don't so .... using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { tgt = 1402 }
NR == FNR {
    file2[$1] = $0
    next
}
{
    fld = "0000"
    val = "unknown"
    for ( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        if ( $i == tgt ) {
            fld = $i
            if ( $1 in file2 ) {
                split(file2[$1],f)
                val = f[i]
            }
            break
        }
    }
    print $1, fld, val
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
1010089 1402 26
1010121 1402 62
1305789 1402 unknown
3456889 0000 unknown
```

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure though how to run this script. Should I save the first step to and sh file?

Comment: You're welcome. Create a file named `tst.awk` with the contents shown under `cat tst.awk` then execute it as `awk -f tst.awk file1 file1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $ awk 'FNR==NR {for (ii=2;ii<=NF;ii++) if ($ii=="1402") a[$1]=ii;next} 
         {if ($1 in a) {column=a[$1]; print $1,"1402",$column}}' file1 file2
   
  1010089 1402 26
  1010121 1402 62
```

This solution is one of many. It is quite general so it will process all ~300k lines of `file2` even in the event of repeated first column values.
The value "1402" can be placed in any column after the first one in `file1`.

HTH